# Export/Generate Conversation Dialogue? Watson Conversation (Assistant)

Tags: watson, watson-conversation, transcription, watson-assistant

After completion of a conversation in Assistant (Formerly Conversation) - I am looking to post a transcript of the conversation, posting out the text or .txt file, etc. I have not been able to figure out any methods for this, was hoping for any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Watson Assistant API request `GET /v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/logs` to get the conversation logs in a Json format - from there it should be fairly easy to convert that to plain txt (e.g. with a python or js script).

More info about the get logs message endpoint here: [WA API Doc](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/curl.html?curl#logs-api)